# ionic 4 insert mode picture in picture for Android

Tags: ionic4, picture-in-picture

i am doing an app for Android and IOS. For IOS works well background geolocation , but for Android, the system kill the process after 5 min.  I would like to implement mode pip but i don't find documentation about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What specific plugins are you using ?
And show us your AndroidManifest.xml

From : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture

> An activity can enter PIP mode when the user taps the home or recents
> button to choose another app. (This is how Google Maps continues to
> display directions while the user runs another activity at the same
> time.)

You need to declare this :

```
<activity android:name="Activity"
    android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
</activity>
```

If you want your user entering in pip mode if he user presses the home or recents button, you have to override `onUserLeaveHint()` method in `Activity.java` with this:

```
@Override
public void onUserLeaveHint () {
    if (iWantToBeInPipModeNow()) {
        enterPictureInPictureMode();
    }
}
```